# Подскажите можно ли с помощью регулярки вытащить значение из такого массива данных

Tags: регулярные-выражения

```
Дата :            25/06/2019 11:18:49
        Автор  отчета :     Лаборатория
 Хроматограмма  :      Брусковый  14.06.19
 Дата  запуска :      17/06/2019 12:46:29
  Файл:                D:\Mult\Data\  БП\190617124629
        Дата  записи : 17/06/2019 13:11:30
  Метод:                      БП.mtw
        Дата  записи : 14/06/2019 09:22:11
 Оператор  анализа  :  Лаборатория
 Номер  анализа :     2930
 ПРОБА :             1,85
  Пробирка № :        1
 Объем :             1.0    мкл
 Разведение  :        1.00
 Количество  :        1.00
 КОЛОНКА :
 Размер :               2.0   х60  мм
  ПОДВИЖНАЯ  ФАЗА A:
  Скорость подачи :   0.00   mL/min
  MPa
     mV
                                       1
    0.45
    0.40
         ִֻװ
    0.35                                                ֿ◌ֱ◌
    0.30
                                                        0.004 
    0.25
    0.20
    0.15
    0.10
    0.05
       0  1  2  3  4 5  6  7  8  9 10 11 1213 14 15 16 1718 19 20 21 2223 24 25   םטל
         РЕЗУЛЬТАТЫ   РАСЧЕТА
 Метод  расчета :      Заказной
 Стандарт :            БП
   No   Время    Высота      Площадь           Конц .            Название
          мин         mV     mV* сек
   1   11.36     0.28      22.30             0
   2   17.11     0.19       8.45      0.003623         БП
 __________________________________________________________________
   2      25     0.47      30.75      0.003623
 Отчет  выдан  программой   МультиХром
  © 1993-2008  ЗАО  Амперсенд
```

Текст выводится именно в таком виде и с таким форматированием. Вопрос как получить значение 0.003623 с помощью регулярного выражения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать `/_{32,}\n.*?(-?\d+\.?\d*)$/m` и брать первую группу:

```js
function f(s) {
  return s.match(/_{32,}\n.*?(-?\d+\.?\d*)$/m)[1]
}

console.log(f(document.getElementById('text').value))
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
textarea { box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%; height: calc(100vh - 24px); resize: none; }
```

```html
<textarea id=text readonly>Дата :            25/06/2019 11:18:49
        Автор  отчета :     Лаборатория
 Хроматограмма  :      Брусковый  14.06.19
 Дата  запуска :      17/06/2019 12:46:29
  Файл:                D:\Mult\Data\  БП\190617124629
        Дата  записи : 17/06/2019 13:11:30
  Метод:                      БП.mtw
        Дата  записи : 14/06/2019 09:22:11
 Оператор  анализа  :  Лаборатория
 Номер  анализа :     2930
 ПРОБА :             1,85
  Пробирка № :        1
 Объем :             1.0    мкл
 Разведение  :        1.00
 Количество  :        1.00
 КОЛОНКА :
 Размер :               2.0   х60  мм
  ПОДВИЖНАЯ  ФАЗА A:
  Скорость подачи :   0.00   mL/min
  MPa
     mV
                                       1
    0.45
    0.40
         ִֻװ
    0.35                                                ֿ◌ֱ◌
    0.30
                                                        0.004 
    0.25
    0.20
    0.15
    0.10
    0.05
       0  1  2  3  4 5  6  7  8  9 10 11 1213 14 15 16 1718 19 20 21 2223 24 25   םטל
         РЕЗУЛЬТАТЫ   РАСЧЕТА
 Метод  расчета :      Заказной
 Стандарт :            БП
   No   Время    Высота      Площадь           Конц .            Название
          мин         mV     mV* сек
   1   11.36     0.28      22.30             0
   2   17.11     0.19       8.45      0.003623         БП
 __________________________________________________________________
   2      25     0.47      30.75      0.003623
 Отчет  выдан  программой   МультиХром
  © 1993-2008  ЗАО  Амперсенд</textarea>
```

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95397/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-vladimr-vladimirovoch).

Comment: Я попробовал вот так \d{1}.\d{6} и нашел два совпадения, как мне только использовать одно из них, Ну в ответе правильном тоже нужно брать группу, но это неприемлемо так как в результате работы выражения нужно получить только одно значение явно

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch, запостил отдельным ответом.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант без использования групп (ищет число с 1 знаком до точки и 6 после, за которым не следует горизонтальная линия):

```js
function f(s) {
  return s.match(/\d\.\d{6}(?![\s\S\r\n]*_{32,})/g)
}

console.log(f(document.getElementById('text').value))
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
textarea { box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%; height: calc(100vh - 54px); resize: none; }
```

```html
<textarea id=text readonly>Дата :            25/06/2019 11:18:49
        Автор  отчета :     Лаборатория
 Хроматограмма  :      Брусковый  14.06.19
 Дата  запуска :      17/06/2019 12:46:29
  Файл:                D:\Mult\Data\  БП\190617124629
        Дата  записи : 17/06/2019 13:11:30
  Метод:                      БП.mtw
        Дата  записи : 14/06/2019 09:22:11
 Оператор  анализа  :  Лаборатория
 Номер  анализа :     2930
 ПРОБА :             1,85
  Пробирка № :        1
 Объем :             1.0    мкл
 Разведение  :        1.00
 Количество  :        1.00
 КОЛОНКА :
 Размер :               2.0   х60  мм
  ПОДВИЖНАЯ  ФАЗА A:
  Скорость подачи :   0.00   mL/min
  MPa
     mV
                                       1
    0.45
    0.40
         ִֻװ
    0.35                                                ֿ◌ֱ◌
    0.30
                                                        0.004 
    0.25
    0.20
    0.15
    0.10
    0.05
       0  1  2  3  4 5  6  7  8  9 10 11 1213 14 15 16 1718 19 20 21 2223 24 25   םטל
         РЕЗУЛЬТАТЫ   РАСЧЕТА
 Метод  расчета :      Заказной
 Стандарт :            БП
   No   Время    Высота      Площадь           Конц .            Название
          мин         mV     mV* сек
   1   11.36     0.28      22.30             0
   2   17.11     0.19       8.45      0.003623         БП
 __________________________________________________________________
   2      25     0.47      30.75      0.003623
 Отчет  выдан  программой   МультиХром
  © 1993-2008  ЗАО  Амперсенд</textarea>
```

Comment: Увы кавычки и скобки ненужны, нужно просто значение  в виде числа,одно

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch, кавычек и скобок нет, то так массив всех вхождений выводится.

Comment: Ну вот как то мне нужно взять одно значение самое последнее, чтобы просто вернулось одно число. Просто суть в том, что есть программа ,которая берет в себя регулярное выражение, по этому оно, это выражение должно явно возвращать только одно число, по логике ничего больше не нужно. Интересующее меня значение всегда стоит в конце всего текста под чертой.

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch, да проверь ты наконец! Надоело уже.

Comment: Так вроде правильно, но для меня не применимо, Ваш вариант возвращает данные, но они увы не перевариваются моим софтом. Я не знаю с чем это связано. Вот я сейчас сделал выражение (\d\.\d{6}) нахожу что нужно но, оно тоже возвращает два значения, (мой софт говорит что найдено все. но ошибка из за того, что два значения найдено ,а не одно, всмысле возвращается одно)Как вернуть просто одно найденное значение увы незнаю.

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch, перед тобой регулярка - что, сложно себе её в код воткнуть???

Comment: Спасибо получилось