# Вопрос алгоритмический, как разложить текст по ячейкам

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Есть у меня задача, на входе есть текст, (массив строк), мне нужно как то разложить этот текст по ячейкам в таблице (какой нибудь грид), далее имея этот грид, я, зная адрес ячейки, могу взять оттуда значение, которое там находится. Суть этого мероприятия в том, что у меня есть  небольшие по объему текстовые файлы с одинаковым форматированием, и когда этот файл видится в виде грида, таблицы, то пользователь просто выбирает ячейку с данными которые ему нужны и все, далее из этой ячейки я получаю данные и обрабатываю их. Конечно понимаю, что может быть сложность в том как делить содержимое файла. Сейчас эта задача решается с помощью регулярных выражений. Но для обычного пользователя это очень сложно. А хочется проще, выделили визуально ячейку с данными и все. Может есть уже библиотеки, которые могут помочь в решении задачи этой или у кого то опыт подобный был.
Приведу пример, есть файл с такой структурой и таким форматированием.

```
Дата :            25/06/2019 11:18:49
        Автор  отчета :     Лаборатория
 Хроматограмма  :      Брусковый  14.06.19
 Дата  запуска :      17/06/2019 12:46:29
  Файл:                D:\Mult\Data\  БП\190617124629
        Дата  записи : 17/06/2019 13:11:30
  Метод:                      БП.mtw
        Дата  записи : 14/06/2019 09:22:11
 Оператор  анализа  :  Лаборатория
 Номер  анализа :     2930
 ПРОБА :             1,85
  Пробирка № :        1
 Объем :             1.0    мкл
 Разведение  :        1.00
 Количество  :        1.00
 КОЛОНКА :
 Размер :               2.0   х60  мм
  ПОДВИЖНАЯ  ФАЗА A:
  Скорость подачи :   0.00   mL/min
  MPa
     mV
                                       1
    0.45
    0.40
         ִֻװ
    0.35                                                ֿ◌ֱ◌
    0.30
                                                        0.004 
    0.25
    0.20
    0.15
    0.10
    0.05
       0  1  2  3  4 5  6  7  8  9 10 11 1213 14 15 16 1718 19 20 21 2223 24 25   םטל
         РЕЗУЛЬТАТЫ   РАСЧЕТА
 Метод  расчета :      Заказной
 Стандарт :            БП
   No   Время    Высота      Площадь           Конц .            Название
          мин         mV     mV* сек
   1   11.36     0.28      22.30             0
   2   17.11     0.19       8.45      0.003623         БП
 __________________________________________________________________
   2      25     0.47      30.75      0.003623
 Отчет  выдан  программой   МультиХром
  © 1993-2008  ЗАО  Амперсенд
```

Вот так показывается файл пользователю сейчас, я хочу сделать проще, пользователь указал одно место в этом всем файле визуально 0.003623 (тыкнул в ячейку где это значение), программа запомнила место и при следующей загрузке другого файла но с таким же форматированием, проста взяла данные из ячейки, для этого мне и нужно сделать из этого текста таблицу.

Comment: я ничего не понял. Если вам надо разложить текст на 2мерный массив, разложите его на 1 мерный, а потом одномерный переведите в 2мерный. НО не понятна логика вашего разложения текста в таблицу.

Comment: какие то файлы, строки, форматирование, перечитал и стало ещё хуже :)

Comment: @tym32167 логика простоя визуально пользователь тыкает в значение показателя которое он видит и без всяких регулярных выражений  программа запоминает ячейку где  этот показатель и всегда берет оттуда данные, так как у всех файлов форматирование одинаковое.потом есть другая пачка файлов с другим форматированием, пользователь также берет и тыкает пальцев в нужный показатель и  далее из этой ячеики берутся данные.

Comment: Нужно чтобы программа по этой ячейке. запоминала место в текстовом файле,  откуда брать данные, то есть загрузился файл, разложился в таблицу,  зная заранее ячейку, ее адрес, я беру от туда данные.

Comment: вы добавляете ещё больше сложность, говоря о каких то показателях. Наверное, будет не лишним привести пример

Comment: @tym32167, он хочет автоматический поиск аналогичного места в тексте по клику пользователя.

Comment: Не зная структуру текста - никак. Точнее, таким гугл занимается в своих поисковых алгоритмах, вряд ли тебе подобное в ответе выдадут.

Comment: @Qwertiy я идею понял, но не понял детали. Что знаит аналогичного? Что значит показатель? Что значит одинаковое форматирование? Как зная мето с одном файле найти это место в другом? По смещению?

Comment: @tym32167, вот поэтому и никак. А вот как минимум один пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/996707/178988

Comment: Добавил в вопрос пример.

Comment: Открываете этот текст в `RichTextBox`. Пользователь выделяет, что ему нужно, жмёт на кнопку "Запомнить". Сохраняем значения `richTextBox.SelectionStart` и `richTextBox.SelectionLength`. В следующий раз, когда нужно, юзер жмёт кнопку "Восстановить". Задаём значения `richTextBox.SelectionStart` и `richTextBox.SelectionLength`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov нужно чтобы я программно знал место сохраненное. Пользователь только указал место где содержатся нужные данные, один раз открыл файл, и мне нужно как то это место пометить для дальнейшего использования. А дальше поступает новый файл и он автоматически обрабатывается, так как я знаю,какое место пометил  пользователь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Набросал пример программки на Windows Forms.

Текст показывается в `RichTextBox`. Пользователь выделяет нужную информацию, жмёт кнопку "Store"/"Запомнить". Значения `richTextBox.SelectionStart` и `richTextBox.SelectionLengt` запоминаются в переменных. Можно их добавлять в список, чтобы помнить много позиций. Можно сохранять их далее в файл/базу данных.

Когда нужно восстановить ранее запомненные позиции, пользователь жмёт кнопку "Restore"/"Восстановить". Задаём свойства `richTextBox.SelectionStart` и `richTextBox.SelectionLength` равные ранее запомненным.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinFormApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        RichTextBox richTextBox;
        Button storeSelectedButton;
        Button restorePositionButton;

        int selectionStart;
        int selectionLength;

        public Form1()
        {
            Size = new System.Drawing.Size(500, 500);
            richTextBox = new RichTextBox { Parent = this, Dock = DockStyle.Top, Height = 400, HideSelection = false, ReadOnly = true };
            richTextBox.Text = File.ReadAllText("test.txt");

            storeSelectedButton = new Button { Parent = this, Top = richTextBox.Bottom + 20, Text = "Store" };
            restorePositionButton = new Button { Parent = this, Top = storeSelectedButton.Top, Left = storeSelectedButton.Right + 50, Text = "Restore" };

            storeSelectedButton.Click += StoreSelectedButton_Click;
            restorePositionButton.Click += RestorePositionButton_Click;
        }

        private void StoreSelectedButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            selectionStart = richTextBox.SelectionStart;
            selectionLength = richTextBox.SelectionLength;

            // save values to file/database
        }

        private void RestorePositionButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // load values from file/database

            richTextBox.SelectionStart = selectionStart;
            richTextBox.SelectionLength = selectionLength;
        }
    }
}
```

Если другой файл будет *точно* с таким же форматированием, то выделение точно сработает и на нём. Но если есть разница хотя бы в пробелах, то выделение "сползёт".

Comment: но ведь одинаковое форматирование != одинаковый контент

Comment: @tym32167 да тут вы правы, но в моем случае количество символов в результате всегда одно и тоже, можно выделить гораздо больше область, и с этим работать в ответе на мой вопрос это получилось.

Comment: Спасибо, с этим уже можно работать, я получаю позицию данных в том месте где выделил его. А если для полноты эксперимента добавить два поля для ввода позиции и длинны, то можно из предыдущего файла использовать эти значения и проверить попадет ли точно в нужную область